# Magento Report issue - Only filter option available, no table showing up

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento-2.3, magento2.2

I'm new to Magento(V 2.3.1). Got an issue under **Reports > Sales > Orders**. I see only the filter option and there is no table to display the result. Not sure how this can be solved. Any help would be great.
[Screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUae7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to refresh your statistics? Admin path: **Reports > Statistics > Refresh Statistics**

Comment: You are right. The issue resolved after doing the above steps.